# Understanding Residual plots and how to transform my data to not violate the normal assumption

Tags: r, experiment-design

Hello I would like to know, whether my residual vs fitted plot is okay ie does not violate the normality assumption [image: residual vs fitted]

The design is a random block design

as well as the histogram seems to be binomial or an F. can someone recommend a transformation i can use so that i can not violate the anova assumptions[image]

Comment: Before you spend too much time worrying about normality of residuals you might like to read https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29731/regression-when-the-ols-residuals-are-not-normally-distributed which explains the issues.

Comment: Is your outcome variable continuous ? The plot indicates that it might not be and you might need to fit a (maybe poisson) glm

Comment: Your response is a count, right?

Answer (score 1):

The first graph indicates that variance of residuals increases along the fitted value. So the first thing is to find an transformation (maybe **log transformation**) such that the variance being a constant. Then check the normality.

Comment: Umm, the plot rather indicates a discrete response variable (judging from the variable name probably a count). OP should use a GLM.